# How to write regular expression with global search in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to create a regular expression for reduce the state name in an abbreviation. For example, the string "New York" should be replaced with "NY".

I came with this `/[^[A-Z]/g`. I tested it here: http://regexr.com and it works!

When I write that in objective-c code it does not work.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^A-Z]/g" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *abbreviation = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self.state options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.state length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

I'm not very experienced with regular expressions. Why is that not working? 
(It can be a dumb mistake, but I can`t find it)

Comment: your code will replace match string to empty, what is value of *UF

Comment: I edited the question to give a best understanding.

Comment: " I tested it here: http://regexr.com and it works!" Yes, but regex comes in flavors. You tested the wrong flavor. :)

Comment: @matt Do you know any engine that I can play with regex for iOS world?

Comment: RegexKnife (app store) or NSRegexTester (free desktop application) are good to start with.

Comment: @ikkarion you can use Xcode Find feature!  you can change find option by click "Edit Find Options"->"Matching Style"->"Regular Expression". Search result's is really what you get when programming in iOS

Comment: Thanks! I will study the tools and regular expressions too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is `\g` in regex? try `@"[^A-Z]"` or `@"[^A-Z]+"` with options `0`:

in iOS using regex to search or replace is really greedy, searching or replacing scopes is depend on `range` in regex function's parameters.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^A-Z]" options:0 error:&error]; // or @"[^A-Z]+"

NSString *UF = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:@"New York" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"New York" length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The @"[^A-Z]+" works! I don't know what /g is suppose to mean. I just know that is 'saves' the state of the search.

Comment: @ikkarion yes \g is Global search in other language. And not work in iOS